# How to import JSON framework?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, json, frameworks

I've downloaded the JSON framework DMG from http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/downloads/list.  I followed Option 3 here: http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/wiki/InstallationInstructions.  For the copy files build phase, I set path to ~/Library/Frameworks/JSON.framework. Buid failed.  I then tried setting it to my project root.  Build failed.

I keep getting this error:

```
<JSON/JSON.h>: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that that is not a Google product—it's just hosted on Google's public code-hosting site.

Comment: Yeah, here's the relevant (as of 2009-08-22) point in the list of all official Google projects on that site: http://code.google.com/hosting/projects.html?filter=0&start=190

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to put the framework in Library, at least under Xcode 3.1.3. Here's what you do:

1. Put the JSON framework source tree in your source tree.
2. Add the framework project to your project.
3. Get Info on your target, click + under the Direct Dependencies list, and choose the framework target from the framework project.
4. Right-click on your target in the group tree and choose “New Build Phase▶ Copy Files”. In the window that results, choose Frameworks as the destination.
5. Add the framework target (which will transmogrify into its build product) to the Copy Files phase.
6. Add the framework target (which will transmogrify) to your target's Link with Libraries phase.

Comment: I'm lost with what you've posted.  1.) Ok  2.) There is no .xcodeproj file 3.) What?  4.) Come again?  5.) & 6.) No idea.

Comment: I've clarified my instructions. As for step 2: Yes there is.

Comment: Thanks.  I went with Option 1 from above link and it worked fine.

Comment: Can anyone share out steps for getting this work on Xcode 4.0?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what does Source Tree mean and How to add the Framework Project to the project? Can u please post the detailed steps on how to add the Framework to Xcode? Please help me.

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa: By “source tree”, I mean the folder containing the project, sources, resources, etc. As for adding the framework project to the application project, drag the framework project from the Finder into the application project's Project Navigator in Xcode 4 (Groups and Files list in Xcode 3).

Comment: @PeterHosey: Thanks for the clarification above. Can u please explain the points 3,4 and 5?

Comment: @PeterHosey: I am using Xcode 4.0 Version. Can u please post me the steps and the right dmg file where i can download the same?